# Find $\int_0^1 \ln^n(x) dx$.

Tags: calculus

> Find $$ \int_0^1 \ln^n(x) dx$$

Do I have to find a recursion here? And if so, how?

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: Should I do $u = \ln(x)$ and $dv = dx$?

Comment: This is Euler's first integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History).

Answer (score 7):

Consider:
$$I= \int_0^1 \log^n x\,dx $$

Setting $\log x =t $

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^0 t^n e^t \,dt $$
Letting $t=-p$:
$$ I =(-1)^n \int_0^\infty p^n e^{-p}\,dp $$

Therefore,
$$ I= (-1)^n \Gamma(n+1) = (-1)^n n!$$

Comment: Very nice. +1.${}$

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this:

Let,
$$I = \int_0^1 x^a\ \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{1}{a+1}$$

Now, differentiate $I$ with respect to $a$:

$$I^\prime = \int_0^1 x^a\ \ln x\ \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{-1}{(a+1)^2}$$

See the pattern? Recursively, this brings us to:

$$I^{(n)} = \int_0^1 x^a\ \ln^n x\ \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{(-1)^n n!}{(a+1)^{n+1}}$$

This is the general form, for your case plug in $a=0$ and you get $(-1)^nn!$.

Comment: Feynmann lives!  +1 -Mark

Comment: Great answer +1 but pardon my ignorance and please explain @dr.mv s remark

Answer (score 4):

Take $u = (\log x)^n$ and $dv = dx$. You'll obtain:

$$I_n = -nI_{n-1}, \forall \ n \ge 1$$

With $I_0 = 1$.

Then:

$$I_n = (-n)(-(n-1))(-(n-2))(\cdots)(-1)I_0 = (-1)^n n! $$